# How to find the screen names and fields in that screen in VB application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working in some capital market application. It's designed using VB. Every time I have to search for the different screens and the fields and its navigation.

Can I get the list of all the screen names and the fields (Text fields or drop boxes) included in that screen and the navigation to that screen from the home page?

Comment: Where you write "screen", do you mean "form"?

Comment: ...and are you talking the app you wrote or VS?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the "Document Outline" in Visual Studio? GOTO View>>Other Windows>>Document Outline  while on a form/screen/page.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all opened Forms: Use My.Application.OpenForms or Application.OpenForms (see [How do I unload all open forms in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589503/how-do-i-unload-all-open-forms-in-vb-net/)). To get a list of all controls in a Form: Use the Controls property (see [loop over all textboxes in a form, including those inside a groupbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox)).